# a confusion about answer "yes" and "no" to some complicated question

Tags: grammar

I got confused about the usage of "yes" and "no".

I knew in English,"yes" or "no" should response to the meaning of sentence.

take a example. assuming a stuff is available.

```
     is it available? -yes.
     isn't it available? -yes.
```

but I not sure to  say "yes" or "no" when someone ask a complicated question with double-negatives.

```
     is it unavailable? 
     isn't it unavailable?
```

Comment: When there's negation in the question, don't use just _Yes_ or _ No_. Repeat the verb phrase in the answer: _It isn't unavailable_ or _It is unavailable_. If you do that, you can preface either one with _Yes_ **or** _No_, since they refer to your perception of the answer, not the question.

Comment: That isn't what the OP is asking. The question is about how adding the prefix 'un-'  changes the response.

Comment: A single word *yes* or *no* is always going to be confusing where the question is posed in the negative. Thus we should answer in the form *yes I do* or *no I don't* irrespective of how the question is posed. The Japanese, on the other hand, give a literal answer to the question and, when speaking English, in reply to *You don't go to the shop on Mondays, do you?* may well answer *yes I don't*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it unavailable?

(a) If it is unavailable then you answer:

"Yes." or "Yes, it is unavailable."

(b) If, on the other hand, it is **not** unavailable then it is available. You have a choice and can answer:

"No." or "No it isn't unavailable.

or you can say:

"No, it is available." or "No. In fact it **is** available."

---

**Discussion**

So far I have only dealt with the first part, i.e. the question "Is it unavailable?"  In theory I should now go on to explain the second part, i.e. "Isn't it unavailable?"

**However**

In real-life, no-one would ever ask that.

If you try to memorise all these different responses you will become hopelessly confused. The key is not memorisation, it is understanding *the purpose of the question*.

A question is a request for information. The best way to deal with it is simply to give the information!  You know whether X is available or not. Therefore you can simply say which is true. No matter how complicated the question, reply by talking about availabilty.

**Example**

Me: Good morning, I want some X. Is true or not true that X is available or isn't available, or is it?

You: We have plenty of X available. How much would you like?

or

You: I'm sorry, we don't have any X available today. Would you like me to order some for you?

**Conclusion**

In real life we don't try to imitate the form of a complicated question with double-negatives -- we simply answer.

Comment: But imagine you walk into  a store to buy a purple widget and when you get to the widget shelf a sign says,  "We are no longer selling purple widgets." As you wait at the counter to pay for your other purchases, another customer walks up to the clerk with a purple widget, pays for it, and dashes off. You approach the counter with a perplexed look and say, "That man just bought a purple widget. Isn't it unavailable?" A logical question. The clerk might say, "Yes, it is now unavailable, but Mr. Smith had it on layaway.

Comment: You might *ask*  that and I might *ask* that.  However, if I was the clerk I'd actually *say*, "That one was on layaway."   You don't want the other customer's life-history or a detailed breakdown of the past and present stock.  You just want to know if there is a purple widget you can have.

Comment: a very detailed and easy to understanded answer.  and I have made sense of  the usage of "yes" and "no" now.thank you